# MySQL giving me syntax error referring to characters that don't exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `company_db`;
CREATE DATABASE `company_db`;
USE `company_db`;

CREATE TABLE department(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    department_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL;
);

CREATE TABLE roles(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    salary DECIMAL,
    department_id INT;
);

CREATE TABLE employee(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    role_id INT NOT NULL,
    manager_id INT;
);
```

Here's my code above. When I try to run this schema file I get the following errors.

- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

What are they talking about? There isn't even a ')' in line 1. Is there something I'm misunderstanding about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: In the `CREATE` statements, the semicolon should only be at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

You have an abundance of `;`. This terminates each statement, it should not be present within the `create`:

```
CREATE TABLE department(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    department_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE roles(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    salary DECIMAL,
    department_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE employee(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    role_id INT NOT NULL,
    manager_id INT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In each create statement, you have “;” after the last column… this is interpreted as the end of the SQL statement which is causing a syntax error. Just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The line numbers are within each statement, and you have extra semicolons.  So your:

```
CREATE TABLE department(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    department_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL;
);
```

is two statements. The first:

```
CREATE TABLE department(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    department_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL
```

complains about a syntax error at '' on line 3 (the end, where it is expecting a `,` or `)` and sees neither).

And the second:

```
);
```

complains about a syntax error at ')' on line 1 (for obvious reasons).

Comment: wow preciate it i was reading the terminal completely wrong. can't upvote cause im a new account but thanks a lot